# NotificationCompat.Action icon not showing up in notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I want to implement button with icon in push notification. I have custom icon as `Bitmap`, so i convert it to `IconCompat` with `IconCompat.createWithBitmap(bits)`. After that I trigger push notification from app and see the button but without the `Icon`! I've already checked that icon is downloaded and converted without exceptions.

I used the following code to create the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Action button = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(icon, "ACTION", pendingIntent).build();

NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
    .setContentTitle("Title")
    .setContentText("Subtitle")
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .addAction(button)
    .build()

NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
manager.notify(ID, notification);
```

I know that this can be done with custom notifications, but why doesn't the default version work?

Help me figure this out, please.